# How to disable access to jboss admin console in Jboss-eap-5.1

Tags: jboss, console, redhat, jboss5.x

I have a requirement to disable access to jboss admin console. URL for that is http://[hostname]:[port]/admin-console/login.seam

Jboss version is **jboss-eap-5.1**

Operating System is **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)**

I went through blogs/sites, but most of them are talking about enabling the security for console or managing the on-demand deployment. But this is not what we want. In our case, No user (internal/external) should be able to access the admin console.

few of them are:

https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/Admin_Console_Guide/en-US/html/Administration_Console_User_Guide-Accessing_the_Console.html

https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/10479/tip-activating-admin-console-and-jmx-console-in-jboss-5-x-and-securing-access/

This link talks about the same but for version 6x. which has different directory structure than 5x. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/192483

Please Help!!

Comment: After analysis, I came up with these 3 approaches: 1)  remove/rename admin-console.war (My Manager doesn't like this approach)    2) control the admin-console login permission using User roles files, this will still allow to open admin console page but no user can login   3) Disable the access to admin console page at load balancer level , i.e. all the requests to url containing '/admin-console/login' will be restricted.      At this point of time not very sure how the option 2 and 3 are vulnerable to security....If anyone know..please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

**You can disable the jmx console application.
To do it:**

1 - Go to JBoss deploy folder

2 - Rename the folder jmx-console.war to jmx-console.war.rej

**Or, you can remove the jmx-invoker service:**

1 - Go to JBoss deploy folder

2 - Rename the file jmx-invoker-service.xml to jmx-invoker-service.xml.rej

Ps.: Renaming the files to '.rej' is just a way to see that the files are still there (But JBoss will ignore). You can as well delete these files/folders I mentioned.

Comment: Elvis, Thanks for your comment. But my requirement is to disable access to admin console. If you see the jboss v5x or higher, you can see the war file 'admin-console.war' inside deploy folder.

Comment: So, you want let the jmx-console.war as is and deny access to the application (even the login screen) to specific users? I guess the only way is to use a reverse proxy.

Comment: Correct, I want to keep all the files but somehow disable the access to admin console page. I discussed more with my team and we want to disable all the remote access to this admin console page. Even the login screen should not be shown as it is vulnerable to security.  If localhost want then probably they can login and access. One simple way is to remove the admin-console.war file but that is not what our management want. It is more like disable all the remote access to admin console screen.

Answer (score 1):

We have finally decided how to fix this (credit to  Elvis Rocha also for giving the suggestion).

For this, we have made changes at jboss level to disable below URLs

1) **`To disable https://<host>:<port>/admin-console/login.seam`** - `Rename “admin-console.war” file as “admin-console_disabled” under location <jboss_home>/server/<server_name>/deploy`

2) **`To disable https://<host>:<port>/jmx-console`** - `Rename “jmx-console.war” file as “jmx-console_disabled” under location <jboss_home>/server/<server_name>/deploy`

3) **`To disable https://<host>:<port>`** - `Rename “index.html” file as “index_disabled” under location <jboss_home>/server/<server_name>/deploy/ROOT.war`

**Note** - Remember that these are for jboss version 5.1. If you have any other version then file and path might change accordingly.